# open Safari with NSURL using web link in get variable

Tags: objective-c, get, mobile-safari, nsurl

I need open link kind of "http://www.web.com/?text=link =) http://google.ru is goooooood"

```
message=@"http://www.web.com/?text=link+=)+http://google.ru+is+goooooood";
twitter=[NSURL URLWithString:message];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:twitter];
```

But it doesn't work.
safari opens link: "http://www.web.com/?text=link =) ".
But I need all text.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should URL encode your parameters (special char in your patameters) you can use following function to url encode

```
- (NSString *)stringByURLEncode:(NSString *)param {

    NSMutableString *tempStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:param];
    [tempStr replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [tempStr length])];


    return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempStr] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

Your message variable should look something like this -

```
message=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.web.com/?text=%@",[self stringByURLEncode:@"link+=)+http://google.ru+is+goooooood"]];
```